# Convergence of convolution of $L^p$ function with a sequence of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

let $h_n\in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^d)$ s.t. $\int h_n dm = 1$ and $\operatorname{supp}(h_n)\to {0}$.

I've proven that $h_n\to\delta_0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$, now I'm trying to show that for any $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ where $0\le p<\infty$ I get that $f\star h_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

I tried just manually calculating $\|f\star h_n -f\|_p^p$ and showing that it is bound by something which vanishes as $n$ ascends, but not much luck there. I am not even sure if that is the right approach but I don't have any other ideas.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there no hypothesis about the sign of $h_n$, maybe $h_n\geq 0$?

Comment: I can live with that relaxing assumption

Comment: And are you sure that $p\geq 0$. Is it not $p\in [1,\infty)$?

Comment: Sorry, should be $p<\infty$

Comment: I know how to prove it for $p\in [1,\infty)$. If you want, I can give an outline of it.

Comment: I think I already figured it out. First proving it for continuous functions and then using Lusin's theorem for approximation.

Comment: I would appreciate your outline, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for $p\in [1,\infty)$

1 - Prove that $C_c(\mathbb{R^d})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. You can find the proof [here](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf), in page 72, Theorem 1.3.20,

2 - By using item 1, prove that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$,

3 - Prove that if $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $h_n\star f\rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$,

4 - By using item 2 and 3, you can conclude.

Comment: If you want more specific information, please tell me, because there is a lot of things to do here, and if I write everything, it will take a big text.

Comment: Step 3 is the only crucial one (the rest is very standard).
I think I may have already proven it but I'd still appreciate your outline.